# iOS 9 and 10 - App can't be started after a while since installation

Tags: ios

After a while – which might have been a few weeks or months earlier, but now is more like hours or sometimes even minutes – I can no longer launch the app. All I get is one or a few sessions of app working normally after the installation, then it gets into this state and I can't do anything with it except for delete and reinstall. When I tap the app icon, I get a black screen for 15-25 seconds, then the app crashes.

Here is an excerpt from the log I got via XCode, and more logs are attached:

> Fatal error generating launch image for com.my.app.name:
>   Error Domain=UILaunchStoryboardErrorDomain Code=2 "Error loading:
>   [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not
>   key value coding-compliant for the key delegate."
>   UserInfo={UILaunchStoryboardClientBundleIdentifier=com.axialexchange.ah-newton,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Error loading: [
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key delegate.}

Observations:
When viewing it in the list of recent apps (i.e. double-press the Home button), the app looks fine, and I've seen different screens in different apps there, so it doesn't look like it matters what screen I left the app on.
Reproducible on iPhone 5 / iOS 10.1.1 and iPad 2 / iOS 9.3.5.
Never seen it on iPhone 5S /iOS 8.4.1.
Restarting the device doesn't help.

Comment: Can you give us more details about your launch screen? Code, explanation, anything?

Comment: The error "[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]" generally i have observed when there is no property variable set. Could you check once all the property variables are associated.